# jquery - Block specific links before a page fully loads and binds click events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal dialog plugin written in jquery, that binds to the click event of all of the <a> elements with a specific class.

The modal dialog 'fetches' a page via AJAX, which is declared under the 'href' parameter of the <a>  element.

Everything works fine, but - when a user clicks the <a> link before the page was fully loaded and ready (before the click event is binded to the element) - the browser navigates to the page declared in the 'href' parameter.

Any ideas of how to prevent this behavior? An ideal situation would be to ignore clicks on these elements before the page has fully loaded. Client-side performance is crucial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to avoid inline scripting, then you could utilise jQuery's [live() method](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) to bind an event handler for elements that have not yet been added to the DOM:

1) Be sure to include jQuery in the `<head>` and not the `<body>`, since we need to initiate the following code *before* any elements in the body are created.

2) Include the following, also in the `<head>` (e.g. as an external js file):

```
$("a").live("click", function(){// Use a more specific selector than "a" if poss.
  getAjax( // This is your Ajax function. Adapt as required.
      $(this).attr('href') // Pass in the <a>'s href attribute.
  );
  return false; // Cancel the default click handler, to prevent page redirect.
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically you'll avoid directly coding any href into the  tag.  Instead set href="javascript:void(0)" and handle the submission with jQuery.

Do something like this:

```
<a onclick="SomeJQueryCall()" href="javascript:void(0)">Click Me!</a>
```

And here's the jQuery script:

```
function SomeJQueryCall() {
    //ask the web server for some AJAX xml
    $.get(SomeUrl, null, SomeCallBackFunction(), "xml");
}
```

Comment: thanks! this should work but we are trying to avoid inline scripting in pages markup and instead we try to manage all events bindings in external JS files